# Get Weekly Calendar to display.

Tags: display

On my IPhone, my ICal calendar displays only a monthly calendar.
How do I switch it so I can see a weekly calendar?
I have clicked on 'TODAY" ; CALENDARS; AND INBOX, and find no way to switch to a weekly display.

Answer (score 1):

Hold your iPhone in landscape orientation. Calendar will show five days, which is kind of close to a week.

Answer (score 0):

iPhone build-in Calendar does not have real weekly view.
Tap the list toggle in month view to disabled the "daily event show"
and then tap any day in month view, you can go into day view, but with weekly title.